# Moving content to another site

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

I installed Drupal 8 on a server and I'm trying to move all my content to a different installation with a different UUID. Since the installations have different UUIDs, I am not able to use the content synchronization module.

What should I use to transfer  the site content to a different site? Would changing the site UUID work? If the answer is yes, how should I do it?

Comment: Try following these link https://www.optasy.com/blog/how-migrate-content-your-drupal-8-site-another I used same and achieved all my content copy to another site.

Comment: Instead of JSON better use the D8 migration source https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_drupal_d8, now moved to core, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2940334